# Invalid property value for paragraph tag with border bottom line

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have header component where active element is shown with bottom border line with padding. Here is this component with styles.

```
<div class="account-header">
  <div class="account-header-inner">
    <div v-for="item in accountHeaderItems" :key="item.title" :class="[item.active ? 'active' : '']" class="item-box">
      <p :class="[item.active ? 'active' : '']" class="item" @click="changeSubpage(item)">
        {{item.title}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And styles:

```
.account-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  .account-header-inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid v.$main-color-light;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 930px) { width: 100%; }
    .item-box {
      height: calc(100% - 15px);
      padding-top: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      &.active { border-bottom: 3px solid v.$main-color; }
      .item {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
        color: rgba(#fff, 0.5);
        transition: .2s;
        &.active { color: v.$main-color-light;}
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px) { font-size: 12px; }
      }
      .item:hover { color: v.$main-color-light; }
    }
  }
}
```

So, on matter how and where I try to add padding bottom to active element it doesn't work and on page it looks like this:

[image]

Also, when I was trying to fix it in browser styles, it says `Invalid property value`.

I can't get what is wrong. It doesn't seem like I overwrite styles somewhere else in my project.

**EDIT**

Look how it looks like when I set `padding-bottom` property:

```
.item-box {
      height: calc(100% - 15px);
      padding-top: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      &.active { border-bottom: 3px solid v.$main-color; }
      .item {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
        color: rgba(#fff, 0.5);
        transition: .2s;
        &.active { color: v.$main-color-light;  padding-bottom: 15px; }
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px) { font-size: 12px; }
      }
      .item:hover { color: v.$main-color-light; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You're not showing above what's the value you're trying to pass to `padding-bottom`. And what exact syntax you're using (shorthand, verbose, etc...). Please update with the exact code you have tried. I [assure you](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6ckuvaqL/) `padding-bottom` works on `<p>` elements. My wild guess is you had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding-bottom` on the active class itself.

for example `5px`

```
&.active { border-bottom: 3px solid v.$main-color; padding-bottom: 5px; }
```

or you can use `style` directive.

```
    <div class="account-header">
  <div class="account-header-inner">
    <div v-for="item in accountHeaderItems" :key="item.title" :class="[item.active ? 'active' : '']" class="item-box">
      <p :class="[item.active ? 'active' : '']" class="item" :style="{paddingBottom: item.active ? '5px' : 'unset' }" @click="changeSubpage(item)">
        {{item.title}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```